# При нажатии на кнопку возвращает значение

Tags: python, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, qfiledialog, qtoolbutton

Есть кнопка:

```
self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(Dialog)
self.toolButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 10, 31, 21))
self.toolButton.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
```

---

Есть обработчик:

```
ui.toolButton.clicked.connect(from_to_copy)
```

---

функция, которая обрабатывается:

```
def from_to_copy():
    dirlist = ui.file_dialog_2.getExistingDirectory()
    ui.lineEdit.setText(dirlist)
    global from_copy
    from_copy = dirlist
```

Суть проста, при нажатии на кнопку, открывается диалоговое окно, выбираю папку и он сохраняет ее в переменную `dirlist`. 
Мне эти данные нужны в другой функции, которые привязаны к другой кнопке.

Я сделал следующим образом: создал переменную `global from_copy`, присваиваю значение и потом работаю с этой переменной в другой функции. Но, что-то мне подсказывает что это прям костыль.

Как вообще правильно обрабатывать кнопку, чтобы оно возвращало значение.

Типа того:

```
def from_to_copy():
    dirlist = ui.file_dialog_2.getExistingDirectory()
    ui.lineEdit.setText(dirlist)
    return dirlist

form_copy = ui.toolButton.clicked.connect(from_to_copy)
```

Comment: Сразу очень настораживает то, что вы используете глобальные переменные, но это поправимо. Опубликуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick Проблемы как раз таки нету, все работает, но вот меня тоже настараживают глобальные переменные. Я хочу что бы при нажатии на кнопку, вернулось какой то значение. Как последний код

Comment: Можно ли мне весь код этой проги? Смогу помочь. Я сам программирую на PyQt5

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text="Выбираю папку")
        self.toolButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.toolButton.clicked.connect(self.from_to_copy)
        self.toolButton_2 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text="Другая кнопка")
        self.toolButton_2.clicked.connect(self.from_to_other)
        
        self.dirlist = ''                                               # !!!
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(readOnly=True)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.toolButton, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.toolButton_2, 1, 1)
        
        
    def from_to_copy(self):
        self.dirlist = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(       # !!!
            self, 'Выбрать папку для ...'
        )
        if self.dirlist:
            self.lineEdit.setText(self.dirlist)
        else: 
            self.lineEdit.clear()

    def from_to_other(self):            
        self.label.setText(self.dirlist)                                 # !!!


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.resize(400, 150)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @duddeniska что не так?